# Failing to access local media in react native <WebView/>

Tags: react-native, webrtc

I'm learning a bit about webRTC and react-native and am trying to load the webRTC demo site inside a react-native app.

So I've put this in the index.android.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, WebView} from 'react-native';

export default class testRTC extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri:'https://appr.tc/r/<Any random room number>'}}
        />
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('testRTC', () => testRTC);
```

But when running `react-native run-android`, when the WebView loads I get the following message:
"Failed to get access to local media. Error name was NotAllowedError"
I've tried adding the following permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml, unsuccesfully:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I'm trying to undersatnd what I'm missing so I can load the demo app in my testRTC react-native app

Comment: I've been having the same problem. It seems that, somehow, the implementation of WebView does not support asking for permissions on `getUserMedia()`.

Comment: Related RN issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344027/failing-to-access-local-media-in-react-native-webview

Answer (score 1):

After looking through the Android api documentation, appears that the WebView doesn't implement the underlying getUserMedia() chrome API correctly.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView)

Since the android API isn't implemented the react native api doesn't work correctly either.